# Rules of interference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

```
 First premise:   (a^e) →   (c∨d)  
 Second premise    b →  (f^e)  
 Third premise:    f →  a  
 Fourth premise:   ¬d  
 Fifth premise:    b
```

The question tells me to show a valid argument for the conclusion c by using rules of interference.

But from what I learnt in lectures, they have at most 2 variables in one premise.
example:

> H1: p
>      H2: p → ¬q
>
> > Conclusion: ¬q (Modus ponens)

So, I would like to know how to apply all these rules of interference to premises with more than 2 or 3 variables. Since the first premise contains 4 variables, I have no clue where to start. Your help would be appreciated.

---

### I solved the question. Thanks for the help guys. Question closed.

Comment: Hint/remark: proving results in math usually uses multiple statements/propositions at once. You'll need to use each premise to prove that $C$ holds.

Comment: so does that mean I need to break down the first premise into multiple premises?

Comment: Not really, since we don't know if $A$ and $E$ are both true.

Comment: "rules of **inference**" (and not interference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you get started:

From the second and fifth premise we can infer f^e via Modes Ponens

Comment: Thank you for the tips.